# Automatic redirection to start page-C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In gridview ,there is a templatefield which is imagebutton.i'm binding imageurl at runtime(on pageload) based on the document type.if i'm not binding the image,on next postback it loads the startup page.can somebody give the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by startup page?

Comment: Default page of my application.

Comment: so what page is your gridview on? Are you saying that every postback on this page causes it to redirect to your default page? What is causing the postback? paging/sorting/button click?